# How to Check files are present in two different folders

Tags: python

I have two folders with same file names in different location. In some times few files are missing in one folder. How can i get missing file name and location by using python script.

Example:
Folder 1 : File1.xlsx;File3.xlsx;File4.xlsx
Folder 3 : File1.xlsx;File3.xlsx

Folder 1 is static , means new files are not added and removed in this folder
Folder 3 is Dynamic, means new files are added and removed in this folder.

I want to print one message like "File4.xlsx" is missing in the Folder3.

Can you please help me on this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yout can use os:

```
import os


def get_files (wd):
    filenames = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(wd):
        for file in files:
            filenames.append(file)
    return filenames

dir1 = r'C:\folder1'
dir2 = r'C:\folder2'
files1 = get_files(dir1)
files2 = get_files(dir2)

in1_but_not_in2 = list(set(files1)-set(files2))
in2_but_not_in1 = list(set(files2)-set(files1))

print(f'Files in {dir1} but not in {dir2}: {in1_but_not_in2}')
print(f'Files in {dir2} but not in {dir1}: {in2_but_not_in1}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listing  of both directories, convert them into a set and get the difference, something likeb

```
import os

l1 = os.listdir(folder1)
l2 = os.listdir(folder2)

diff = set(l1). difference(l2)
```

Comment: If i want to display Missing file location means which folder is missing file. Ex: Folder 1 is static